# Data Factory keeps getting "untrusted connection" error when logging into on prem SQL Server via IR on VM

Tags: sql-server, security, azure-data-factory

We have:

1. A local SQL Server database
2. A VM with the Integration Runtime installed on it
3. A Data Factory sharing this IR, working (according to the ADF interface)
4. Logins stored in Key Vault for SQL Server auth from data factory to log into the SQL Server via the IR

The connection string properties of the connection appear to be what I want, note encryption is set to off and trustservercertificate=true:

[image: Connection string]

The IR reports as connected and working fine:

[image]

I have tested the SQL Server auth on the VM with the IR installed via the IR's Diagnostics tab. Works OK:
[image]

From Data Factory, I test using the same login parameters on the linked service connected to the IR, which works:

[image]

Note we use a lot of parameters to define the connections, these work fine as well.

I set up a dataset, using the same properties, test connection works:
[image]

Now I set up an easy copy activity using the same parameters, using the same Dataset and the same linked service:

[image]

I also preview the data I want, which works, bringing data back from the server as expected.

This makes no sense to me, I have tested using exactly the same parameters in each step, but a simple copy activity fails when all the other connection tests have succeeded. Anyone have any idea?

NOTE: I have tried setting the Linked Service connection parameters: Encryption = True which *sometimes* means the connection goes through OK. Again, this makes little sense.

Comment: The test had Encrypt Connection unchecked? Why should Data Factory trust the SSL certificate from the on-prem, is there anywhere you can do that, or is that cert actually issued by proper Certificate Authority?

Comment: @Charlieface - Yes, Encrypted connection was turned off. I have "encrypt=false" in the connection string and "TrustServerCertificate=True". Sorry, will make this clear in the question.

Comment: Does SQL Server have Force Encryption on? Clearly it is trying to encrypt, and not trusting the cert, so those parameters don't seem to be working

Comment: @Charlieface - good point, checked and SQL Server isn't forcing encryption.  It's as if Data Factory is the one forcing encryption, but only sometimes (not when the testing connections, but it is when transferring data).

Comment: Hum, `TrustServerCertificate` should have solved it, so maybe it's not using those params at all. Remember different drivers have different connection strings, it's not directly to do with which DBMS you are using

Comment: @Charlieface - yes, that is what I suspect, it's as if it's deciding to ignore the connection parameters and use it's own when transferring data. But when testing the connection, it's using the parameters I specify.

Comment: Note that I am going to try and fix this by getting our security people to issue certificates so the gateway can use encryption when connecting to SQL Server. It will be interesting to see if that fixes the issue. If it does fix it, it indicates Data Factory is occasionally using encryption even when we have told it not to.

Comment: @Charlieface - I may have fixed this by re-installing the integration runtime on the gateway VM. I have re-created and run the same tests, they all seem to be working. However the IR self updates, so it's possible a recent update from Microsoft (I reinstalled an older version, not the most recent) screwed something up. Will update this with the solution if this works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I fixed this by completely uninstalling then re-installing the Integration Runtime on the VM we are using as a gateway box.  This indicates that it can become corrupt, but the corruption is not visible to the user. We could still use the gateway for testing connections, but not for data transfer.  A careful look through of the logs didn't give any clue to the error that had caused the corruption.

The version I reinstalled was exactly the same as what was there previously, so it didn't appear to be an issue with the version (5.2.7695.1).